# Need to restrict user in Kibana to access specific application logs in EFK

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, efk

I would like to implement elastic search and Kibana instance as shared between multiple users, where multiple users can have their applications(services) and write their logs in the same of different files. But when they logged from Kibana they can only able to see their application(s) logs. I am using Fluentd as a log collector

Comment: Please let me know if setting "index_name" in fluend.conf will create an index pattern in elasticsearch that further can be used as different application in kibana ?

Comment: Please provide your thoughts and direction